# Dawn.Guard member validation throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#

I'm using [Guard](https://github.com/safakgur/guard) 1.12.0 for argument validation. I want to validate the length of an array. This is what I tried:

```
Guard.Argument(array, nameof(array)).Member(a => a.Length, i => i.Equal(36));
```

As expected, `a` is my array and `i` is an `ArgumentInfo<int>`. But this [explodes at runtime](https://github.com/safakgur/guard/blob/2a79a903895ded2c4dab7b29e7f830ba9f0a331e/src/Guard.Member.cs#L298) with the error message

> The selector must be composed of member accesses.

What's the correct usage of `Member` to validate the length of an array?

Comment: I know you're probably wanting to figure out why the code sample doesn't work, but couldn't you just use `Guard.Argument(array, nameof(array)).Count(36)`

Comment: @Hayden I'm new to Guard and overlooked that. Thanks! But yeah, I'm curious how to use `Member` properly.

Comment: You can't use member for arrays, only objects.

Comment: @PRMan Arrays are objects.